# How to construct a STL file from blob return type

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers

I have created a service to download STL file from a URL :-

service.ts:-

```
fetchData(filename:string) {

  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/STL');
  return this.http.get(filename, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' });

}
```

How can I construct the STL file now from this response?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.fetchData.subscribe((res) => {
   let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = res.filename;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.remove();
});
```